# Is there a script like tinyslideshow in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm searching a script similar to tinyslideshow in jquery and also compatible with IE versions including 6.

Is there any ?

Comment: This site is to answer code questions. It is not a plug-in suggestion engine.

Comment: @Diodeus could you suggest me a plug-in suggestion engine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this http://www.userfriendlythinking.com/_CustomFiles/flickrGallery/Example-3a-Small-Auto.html or http://slidershowcase.com/jquery-sliders/tiny-slideshow

Answer (score 1):

There is similiar script called adgallery with jquery and supports ie6, 7, 8, 9, chrome and firefox. Decided to use adgallery after struggling a lot with tiny slideshow, which is not in jquery and not supported anymore!

http://adgallery.codeplex.com/releases/view/87584